# new input added in page not run script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with my site, when i reload a content in a DIV with (.load()) 
the radio button don't run the onchange event how i can resolve it?

```
$(window).ready(function(){
                $('input[name="optionsRadios"]').on('change', function(){
                if ($(this).val()=='veloce') {                  
                    //change to "show update"   
                    var senzasped = <?php echo $tot; ?>;                        
                    senzasped += 5;                     
                    $("#prezzotot").text(senzasped);
                    $("#spedizionese").text("Spedizione Veloce");
                    $("#spedizionese2").text("5,00€");                  
                } else  {
                    var senzasped = <?php echo $tot; ?>;
                    senzasped += 3.5;                           
                    $("#prezzotot").text(senzasped);
                    $("#spedizionese").text("Spedizione Normale");
                    $("#spedizionese2").text("3,50€");
                }
            });
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-sped" style="width:100%; height:100px">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:20px">
                        <label>Selezione la spedizione: </label>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1"value="normale" checked>
                                    Spedizione Normale 3,50€
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="veloce">
                                    Spedizione <strong>Veloce</strong> 5,00€
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the event to an element that is not being changed or `document`:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="optionsRadios"]', function() {
```

This is because the element you attached your change listener to gets replaced by `load` and the new input does not have any listeners attached. If you attach your listener to `document` or another parent element that is not being removed, it will work for all matched inputs that exist or ever will be inserted.

Comment: Thanks it's work ! 
Can you explain me the difference? :P Thanks